# use onBackPress to show last fragment with Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragment, onbackpressed

I use basic Bottom Navigation Activity in Android Studio, and how do I do:

1. Make it click navigation once to switch fragment shown, and click twice to renew.
2. Make it press back to previous fragment on the same tab.

I just tried a whole day but only back to fragment from different navigation item.

Here's relative code.

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManger =  getFragmentManager();
  final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManger.beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and MainActivity onBackPressd()

```
  int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
  if (count == 0) {
     super.onBackPressed();
  } else {
     getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you migrate to the new `Android Navigation Components`, then this behavior will be done for you under the hood and becomes merely a one liner for you. Refer to this guide to learn more: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate.

Comment: thanks a lot, I would keep it in mind.